# What if the reducer's input is too big in Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to understand what to do in that case.

For example, I have 1TB of text data, and lets assume that 300GB of it is
the word
"Hello".

 After each map operation, i will have a collection of key-value pairs of <"Hello",1>.

But as I said, this is a huge collection, 300GB and as I understand , the reducer gets all of it and will crush.

What is the solution for this? 
Lets assume that the combiner won't help me here(the WordCount example is just for simplicity) and the data will still be too big for the reducer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intermediate (Mapper) output is stored in the Local File System of the nodes running the mapper task and is cleaned afterwards. Note that this mapper output is NOT stored in HDFS. The reducer indeed gets all the the intermediate key-value pairs for any particular key (i.e.. all 300 GB output for the key 'Hello' will be processed by the same Reducer task). This data is brought to memory only when required.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what if i dont have 300GB space left on my disk? Will it be partitioned?

Comment: To handle this situation, exists a property 'mapreduce.cluster.local.dir', which can be set in mapred-site.xml file. It can contain a list of comma-separated directory paths, which can point to directories on different devices in order to spread disk I/O. If not set, its default value is ${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/local.

Note: The property hadoop.tmp.dir is set in file core-site.xml. Its default value for most linux distributions is '/tmp'.

Refer the below file for reference:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml

Answer (score 4):

The reducer does get all of that data, but that data is actually written to disk and is only brought into memory as you iterate through the Iteratable of values.  In fact, the object that is returned by that iteration is reused for each value: the fields and other state are simply replaced before the object is handed to you.  That means you have to explicitly copy the value object in order to have all value objects in memory at the same time.

Comment: but i as understood, Hadoop doesn't store the intermediate values on disk.Am i wrong?   BTW,Can you tell me where does Spark is different in here?

Comment: Map tasks write their output to the local disk, not HDFS.